# htaccess Page Redirect to URL with no page ID

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This URL

http://www.example.com/news/2138-gideon-rothschild-listed-leading-lawyer-expert-guides

needs to be redirected to this URL

http://www.example.com/news/gideon-rothschild-listed-leading-lawyer-expert-guides.

Here is another example:

http://www.example.com/articles/2140-can-you-trust-your-trust

to

http://www.example.com/articles/can-you-trust-your-trust

The client wants the page id removed from the URL. Can this redirect be done in the htaccess file or do I need to do it using PHP?

Comment: I can be done in htaccess.

Comment: look at mod_rewrite - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You can't do that with htaccess if after you can't open the page without the page ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using a `RedirectMatch` rule.

Place this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(articles)/\d+-(.+)$ /$1/$2
```

Answer (score 0):

The very basic rule could look like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)(.*)$ /$2 [L,R=301]
```

You would need to fine-tune it a bit if you want only news/ or articles/